# Automation test case is working for appium command line tool but not for desktop client

Tags: java, selenium, appium-desktop

PLEASE HELP ME!!!.
I'm trying to automate an android app. I'm using JAVA. 
If i start the appium server from the command line and run the test case, it is working fine. 
But when i start the appium sever using Appium desktop client(Version - 1.13.0), i'm getting an error.
Why does the test case keep failing when using Appium desktop client(Version - 1.13.0) whereas the same code works fine when run with the appium command line tool?

I'm using `Appium(1.14.0)` and `Appium Desktop version(1.13.0)` with Java 8 and along with the following jar files

- Selenium Remote Driver-3.14.0
- Java-client-7.0.0
- Apache commong language file - 3.7

  ```
  public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> InstallInvokeAPK() throws MalformedURLException
  {
  //Define the source folder
  File f1 = new File("src");

  //Define the destination and name of the APK file
  File f2 = new File(f1, "New Driver app-excel-debug.apk");

      //COnfiguration setting to work with the application
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();//Creating an object of Desiredcapabilities class

      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);//Defining the platform
              cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Moto G (5) Plus");//Defining the Mobile handset name

  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "ZY223Z68JG");

      cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 100);//Defining the maximum timeout period to execute command

      cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");      

      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, f2.getAbsolutePath());      

  //Use the Android Driver to work with Android Platform Elements
          AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

  return driver;

  public class TestApp extends Example2{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException 
  {


         AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = InstallInvokeAPK();

      //AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = PackageActivity("com.e9ine.android.driver", "com.e9ine.android.driver.module.AuthenticationModule.view.activity.SpalshScreenActivity");    

         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Username']")).sendKeys("abc@xyz.com");        

      driver.findElement(By.id("editText_password")).sendKeys("1234");

      driver.navigate().back();
  ```

  These are the appium logs:

  > [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.13.0
  >   [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
  >   [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
  >   [HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk","newCommandTimeout":100,"automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":"true","platformName":"Android","udid":"ZY223Z68JG","deviceName":"Moto G (5) Plus"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk","appium:autoGrantPermissions":"true","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Moto G (5) Plus","appium:newCommandTimeout":100,"platformName":"android","appium:udid":"ZY223Z68JG"}]}}
  >   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk","newCommandTimeout":100,"automationName":"UiAutomator2","autoGrantPermissions":"true","platformName":"Android","udid":"ZY223Z68JG","deviceName":"Moto G (5) Plus"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk","appium:autoGrantPermissions":"true","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"Moto G (5) Plus","appium:newCommandTimeout":100,"platformName":"android","appium:udid":"ZY223Z68JG"}]}]
  >   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1565779809999 (16:20:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
  >   [Appium] Appium v1.13.0 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.33.1) session
  >   [Appium] Capabilities:
  >   [Appium]   platformName: android
  >   [Appium]   app: C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk
  >   [Appium]   autoGrantPermissions: true
  >   [Appium]   automationName: UiAutomator2
  >   [Appium]   deviceName: Moto G (5) Plus
  >   [Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 100
  >   [Appium]   udid: ZY223Z68JG
  >   [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"app":"C:\Users\e9ine-QA... were provided
  >   [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
  >   [BaseDriver] Capability 'autoGrantPermissions' changed from string to boolean. This may cause unexpected behavior
  >   [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 384a04e7-e07c-46ce-887e-a4f69f0993f2
  >   [BaseDriver] Using local app 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\Appium\MobileAutomation\src\New Driver app-excel-debug.apk'
  >   [UiAutomator2] Checking whether app is actually present
  >   [ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
  >   [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
  >   [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
  >   [ADB] Getting connected devices...
  >   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
  >   [AndroidDriver] Using device: ZY223Z68JG
  >   [ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
  >   [ADB] Setting device id to ZY223Z68JG
  >   [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
  >   [ADB] Error sending command, reconnecting device and retrying: shell,getprop,ro.build.version.sdk
  >   [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
  >   [ADB] Getting connected devices...
  >   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
  >   [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
  >   [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
  >   [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG forward --remove tcp:8200'
  >   [UiAutomator2] Unable to remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG forward --remove tcp:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: unknown host service'; Code: '1''
  >   [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
  >   [ADB] Error sending command, reconnecting device and retrying: shell,getprop,ro.build.version.sdk
  >   [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
  >   [ADB] Getting connected devices...
  >   [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
  >   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1565779812994 (16:20:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
  >   [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: device still connecting'; Code: '1'
  >   [W3C]     at ADB. (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\adb-commands.js:98:13)
  >   [W3C]     at Generator.throw ()
  >   [W3C]     at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
  >   [W3C]     at _throw (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:29:9)
  >   [W3C]     at run (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:75:22)
  >   [W3C]     at C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:92:30
  >   [W3C]     at flush (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\modules_microtask.js:18:9)
  >   [W3C]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  >   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 3021 ms - 1276
  >   [HTTP]

  Selenium logs:

  > Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: device still connecting'; Code: '1'
  >   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
  >   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-17I5IMK', ip: '192.168.5.208', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
  >   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
  >   remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: device still connecting'; Code: '1'
  >       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
  >       at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
  >       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  >   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
  >   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-17I5IMK', ip: '192.168.5.208', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
  >   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
  >       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:84)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:94)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:95)
  >       at Test.Example2.InstallInvokeAPK(Example2.java:38)
  >       at Test.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:35)
  >   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  >       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  >       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  >       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
  >       ... 14 more
  >   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: device still connecting'; Code: '1'
  >   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
  >   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-17I5IMK', ip: '192.168.5.208', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
  >   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
  >   remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device API level. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\e9ine-QA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223Z68JG shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: device still connecting'; Code: '1'
  >       at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
  >       at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:447:37)
  >       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  >       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  >       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  >       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
  >       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
  >       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
  >       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
  >       ... 19 more

Comment: Please reformat your question, it's unreadable

Comment: Please let me know if any more information is needed. Also, i'm new to stackoverflow. So help me if at all, my question/code/title needs any edits or they can be changed to a more readable and understandable format.

Thank you in advance for your patience and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your `Selenium Remote Driver-3.14.0` dependency, [Appium Java Client 7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0) includes selenium-java, selenium-support and selenium-api versions 3.141.59  as [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). If you particularly need Selenium Remote Driver I would suggest to ramp it up to 3.141.59 to avoid any API inconsistencies.
2. Try resetting your ADB host by running [`adb kill-server` command](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). Prior to launching your Appium test make sure to execute `abd devices` command and double check that your phone is in `connected` state

References:

- [Appium: Troubleshooting](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/troubleshooting/)
- [Appium: Code Examples - Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java)